# remove some special chars from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove two parts of the string in javascript and the string could be in these ways :

`/folder/file.scss` or `/folder/subfolders/_filestwo.scss`

what i want is to remove `.scss` from the end of the file and if file has `_` remove the underscore as well.

and the result should be :

`/folder/file` or `/folder/subfolders/filestwo`

Comment: Have you tried anything?  This is two string replace operations.

Comment: Did you need a regex expression for that?, I mean for a simple string replace. Hmm.

Comment: no didn't know what could be useful replace or regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `(_)?(\w+)\.scss$`

```js
var str1 = '/folder/subfolders/_filestwo.scss';
var str2 = '/folder/file.scss';

var pattern = /(_)?(\w+)\.scss$/;

console.log(str1.replace(pattern, '$2'));
console.log(str2.replace(pattern, '$2'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `replace` function and regular expressions.

```js
const str = '/folder/file.scss'.replace(/\.scss/g, '').replace(/_/g, '');
```

Comment: You mean, it should only remove the underscore at the beginning of the filename? This is not specified in the question, though.